# Is it possible to auto-complete parentheses or quotation marks in emacs?

Tags: emacs, ide, code-completion

I've used XCode and Netbeans, and I've noticed that they have a feature to automatically complete quotation marks or parentheses (and I assume that other IDEs often do this also). I don't know what the name of this feature is, but is there any way to do this in Emacs?

For example, when I type

```
printf("
```

I would like it to automatically input

```
printf("")
```

placing the cursor in between the quotation marks.

Thank you.

Comment: I used such a macro before, but I use so many different editors today (emacs, vs, eclipse, pn) that I couldn't rely on such a feature. Instead I internalized this behavior and can barely type a left-side character without reflexively inserting the corresponding balanced character. Non-programmers that see me doing this think I'm weird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic variant would be [AutoPairs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs). The same effect but a little more sophisticated can also be achieved with [YASnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/).

Comment: It seemed like AutoPairs and Paredit are the two popular suggestions, but it looks like AutoPairs is made to integrate well with YASnippet, which is nice for further code-completion.

Answer (score 3):

If you type M-(, that will insert both a ( and a ), and leave point in between; if you then type M-), that will move point across the closing ).  I use this all the time.

There is also a mode called "paredit" (available from http://mumble.net/~campbell/emacs/paredit.el) which does this sort of thing for quotes as well, and probably other stuff.

Comment: In my configuraton, `M-)` is bound to `move-past-close-and-reindent`, i.e. it opens up a new line. Is there a possibility to just move past the enclosing parenthese without reindenting?

Comment: `M-- C-M-u` might do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Paredit-mode inserts matching closing elements by default, so the while typing you'll see something like `printf()` then `printf("")` and the cursor would be positioned inside quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using code from http://cmarcelo.wordpress.com/2008/04/26/a-little-emacs-experiment/ to do "electric pairs".  As I descibe in [my blog](http://panela.blog-city.com/python_and_emacs_3_balancing_parentheses_and_others.htm) other modes have problems with Python's triple quoted strings.  (A Python peculiarity)

Answer (score 2):

My 5 cents here as well.

```
(setq skeleton-pair t)
(defvar skeletons-alist
  '((?\( . ?\))
    (?\" . ?\")
    (?[  . ?])
    (?{  . ?})
    (?$  . ?$)))

(global-set-key (kbd "(") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
(global-set-key (kbd "[") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
(global-set-key (kbd "\"") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
(global-set-key (kbd "\'") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
```

Next advice will enable the <kbd>backspace</kbd> to deletes the pairs: a(|)b -> ab

```
(defadvice delete-backward-char (before delete-empty-pair activate)
  (if (eq (cdr (assq (char-before) skeletons-alist)) (char-after))
      (and (char-after) (delete-char 1))))
```

Next advice will make `backward-kill-word` (for me is <kbd>M-backspace</kbd>) to delete matching par even if it separated by other text; very handy.

```
(defadvice backward-kill-word (around delete-pair activate)
  (if (eq (char-syntax (char-before)) ?\()
      (progn
 (backward-char 1)
 (save-excursion
   (forward-sexp 1)
   (delete-char -1))
 (forward-char 1)
 (append-next-kill)
 (kill-backward-chars 1))
    ad-do-it))
```

I am trying to move now to paredit, though.

Comment: Since Autopairs doesn't seem to automatically delete pairs, this backwards delete pairs advice looks like a great supplement.

Answer (score 0):

The [autopair](http://code.google.com/p/autopair/) minor mode does exactly what you ask for.