# How to remove the matching character?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I wrote a simple function, that makes emacs add matching quotes (so when I type `"`, I get `"{cursor}"`). But now, it's a major annoyance when I delete the first quote but the second is still remaining.

Is there a way to "listen" for character deletion events, and it the next character is matching the deleted one, delete the next character as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are existing minor modes for this. See [AutoPairs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs) at the EmacsWiki.

[autopair.el](https://github.com/capitaomorte/autopair) has the specific functionality you're describing.

(`electric-pair-mode` in Emacs 24 does not, it would seem).

Related Q&As (mentioning autopair):

- [Intelligent auto closing matching characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718975/intelligent-auto-closing-matching-characters)
- [Is it possible to auto-complete parentheses or quotation marks in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987489/is-it-possible-to-auto-complete-parentheses-or-quotation-marks-in-emacs)
- [How do I get TextMate style quotes in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72732/how-do-i-get-textmate-style-quotes-in-emacs)
- [Automatically closing braces in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023770/automatically-closing-braces-in-emacs)